# Compilation fails because of Lambda function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

Given is a template function which checks if some elements stored in a container (specified by `numElems`) are equal to any of the passed elements `elems`.

```
template<typename MyType>
bool Container<MyType>::elemsEqual(const int & numElems, const std::initializer_list<MyType>& elems)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < numElems; i++) {
         const MyType& currElem = getElem(i);
             if (std::none_of(elems.begin(), elems.end(), [](MyType& elem) {return currElem == elem; })) {
                 return false;
             }       
     }
     return true;
}
```

Compilation aborts with the error message:

> 'currElem' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture
>   mode has been specified

What is wrong here and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research effort. At least google the error message before asking next time.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify how you want to capture the local variables, either by value (creating a copy) :

```
[=](MyType& elem)
```

Or by reference:

```
[&](MyType& elem)
```

Comment: Thx! ``MyType`` must be ``const`` in my case, so ``[=](const MyType& elem)`` respectively ``[&](const MyType& elem)`` is completely correct.